# Unable to click Admob banner adds in iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, admob

I have integrated admob ads into my app on iOS and Android, they were working on both platforms during testing. I was not requesting test ads though and have read that admob may suspend your account/ads if you are clicking on live ads during testing?

I would not have overdone it, a click through here and there...

Could this be the problem? The ads still work fine on the android version of the app and I have one interstitial ad in the app which is actually still clickable on the iOS version of the app.

Has anyone faced these issues before? I have tried contacting admob about the problem but I am still waiting for a response.

I am hoping someone has so information about this because the results I get from google won't help me solve this

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if your code requests a new ad before the first one has closed.

You will receive an email when you are suspended.

Do use test ads when you test, or you will be suspended. I speak from my own experience, in both cases.